# Send user and admin confirmation email

Tags: php, symfony, email

I create a service for sending an email when the form is send. I receive it well rated admin but I would like to send it to the user who has completed the form a confirmation by email provided that the email field has been filled. Here is my service and my controller:

My service

```
public function sendMailInscriptionMjml(Invite $invite, $mailTo)
{
    $subject = 'Inscription invité';
    $template = 'AppBundle:Mail:Invite/inscription.html.twig';
    $templateP = 'AppBundle:Mail:Invite/inscription.txt.twig';

    $this->sendMessage($mailTo, $subject, $template, $templateP, array('invite' => $invite));
}
```

My controller:

```
/**
 * Creates a new invite entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="invite_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $invite = new Invite();

    $form = $this->createForm(InviteType::class, $invite);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($invite);
            $em->flush();

            $this->get('app_mailer')->sendMailInscriptionMjml(
                $invite, $this->getParameter('client_mail_to')
            );

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()
                ->add('success', 'Votre inscription à été pris en compte.');

            return $this->redirect(
                $this->generateUrl(
                    'homepage'
                )
            );
        }
    }

    return $this->render('@App/invite/new.html.twig', array(
        'invite' => $invite,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: dont get the queestion, so the parameter  `client_mail_to` is the admin mail ? or what

Comment: Yes is admin mail this parameter. I would like to send a confirmation email to the email address of the user who has completed mail. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it, here is the solution in my controller.

```
/**
 * Creates a new invite entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="invite_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $invite = new Invite();

    $form = $this->createForm(InviteType::class, $invite);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $mail = $invite->getEmail();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($invite);
            $em->flush();

            $this->get('app_mailer')->sendMailInscriptionMjml(
                $invite, $this->getParameter('client_mail_to')
            );


            $this->get('app_mailer')->sendEmailInvite(
                $invite, $mail
            );


            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()
                ->add('success', 'Votre inscription à été pris en compte.');

            return $this->redirect(
                $this->generateUrl(
                    'homepage'
                )
            );
        }
    }

    return $this->render('@App/invite/new.html.twig', array(
        'invite' => $invite,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```